# Restrict the range of datetime picker

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, crud, datetimepicker

I am using ASP.NET CORE MVC with EF CORE.

The code below allows me to select the date-time in a date-time picker. However, I want to make it so that the user will not be able to select any DateTime 5 days before and 3 hours before the current DateTime.

Assuming I can't find the JQuery codes for my DateTimePicker, how do I restrict the date-time?

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="DateTime" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="DateTime" class="form-control"   />
     <span asp-validation-for="DateTime" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Model (if needed):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Date/Time ..")]
[Display(Name = "Date/Time")]
public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CreateTest()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTest([Bind("ID,DateTime")] TestModel testModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        testModel.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Add(testModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(testModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom `Validation attribute` to set a date range.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Date/Time ..")]
[Display(Name = "Date/Time")] 
[ValidateDateRange]
public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
```

Here are codes of `ValidateDateRange`.

```
public class ValidateDateRange : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;

        if (dt <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).AddHours(-3))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Date is not in given range.");
        }
    }
}
```

> Screenshots of test

[image]

Links to [Validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-attributes).

Comment: hi, if i want to make so that the user is unable to select a datetime 5 days after and 3 hours before the current datetime, do i change the codes to "dt <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(+5).AddHours(-3)" ?

Comment: With that code, I am able to restrict the user from selecting any datetime 5 days after the current datetime. However, I am still able to select any datetime before the current datetime. What should I change?

Comment: There is no `before` restrict with this If condition "dt <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(+5).AddHours(-3)". So you can select any datetime before the current datetime.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on ```Before``` restrictions?

Comment: `dt <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) && dt >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)`  means range in 5 days after and 5 days before  the current datetime.